# i18next: load option not working as expected

Tags: javascript, i18next

I am using i18next library for my React project and what I want to achieve is to store `en` when my browser's language is exactly not `en` (I don't want to store `en-US` value as default).

When I look up the doc, there is an option called `load` and I set it `currentOnly` now.
However, the default value to store is still `en-US` when my browser's language is `en-US` and `fallback` is `en`. I thought when I set it `currentOnly`, it is supposed to apply fallback value (`en`) because I don't have translation for `en-US`. What am I wrong with this and how can I fix this?

code is like below.

```
import i18n from "i18next";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";
import Backend from "i18next-http-backend";
import LanguageDetector from "i18next-browser-languagedetector";

i18n
  .use(Backend)
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    fallbackLng: "en",
    load: "currentOnly",
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
    },
  });

export default i18n;
```

Comment: the proper load param value should be "languageOnly" according to docs, it will load only language, in your case "en"

Comment: I tried but it didn't change anything. `en-US` will be stored in local storage. @Buggies